# Why is AnyVal the inferred type of `if(i>5) i`?

Tags: scala

```
scala> for(i <-1 to 10) yield { if(i>5) i}
res3: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[AnyVal] = Vector((), (), (),  (), (), 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

Why is this `AnyVal`?  I was expecting `Int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` expression

```
if(i > 5) i
```

evaluates to Unit if the condition is false. `Unit` and `Int` both extend `AnyVal` so that is the most specific type of the expression.

Answer (score 4):

Because your `yield` does not (always) return an Int, like the other answer explains.
I am guessing, what you really wanted to write was

```
for { i <- 1 to 10 if i > 5 } yield i
```

This would indeed give you a `Seq[Int]` (of size 5).

Comment: `for (i <- 1 to 10 if i > 5) yield i`

Comment: "left arrow", actually... But nice answer to go beyond the question.

Comment: Ah, I see. If you just pointed out the typo instead if rewriting the whole statement,  that wouldve ade your comment clearer. On the other hand it did made me see it, so, I guess, did its job :)